My VS Code is unable to recognize Python files; all the code appears green
In all the files, only one Python file is recognized normally (main.py), and the others are not:

Other Python files look like:

I have disabled all plugins to rule out the issue, but the problem persists. Even creating new Python files does not get them recognized correctly.
Does anyone know why this issue is occurring? I don't seem to have found the same error online.

What happens if you comment out the module docstring after import numpy?

use the TextMate Scope inspector to find out why it paints the text green

Just like @rioV8 mentioned you may want to inspect why the whole file was commented.Reinstalling VSCode may resolve the issue aswell.

From my understanding it could be because python isn't being recognised or the Path being incorrect. Maybe use this thread to follow a reinstall and see if that is able to fix the problem.
Majority of the time when I have an issue similar to this my PATH environment variable was not including the correct python version but VS code was seeing it was installed and hence made it difficult for me to diagnose.
Also, it looks like the shebang for the un-recognised file is stating just python in the path #!usr/bin/python. I believe Linux with python3.x installations has a python3 bin folder name instead so check where that python version is installed and see if that's correct. As far as I know there is a difference between both of these. Does it use the same shebang as the file that is working?
